# Using clang-format with IAR embedded workbench

Tags: embedded, iar, clang-format

I have a project in IAR embedded workbench. Is there a way using the tools menu to add in a code formatter such as clang-format? I've managed to call it, but have not set the command line options correctly in order to feed the current file into the formatter.

Simon

Comment: Ok, that is not a question.  It is a statement.  Why would you knowingly set them incorrectly?  You need to at least 1) Indicate you you have tried - the command line you are using, or a screenshot of the dialog perhaps..  2) ask a question.

Comment: Looking at the [user manua](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_UserGuide.ENU.pdf) l don't think file macros are supported in the configure tools - it is not mentioned, but elsewhere the macro `$FILE_PATH$` is used to indicate the current active file - have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

Here are the settings I used.

```
Menu Text: Clang Format
Command: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe 
Argument: --style=file $FILE_PATH$ -i
Initial Directory: $FILE_DIR$
```

These settings require a file .clang-format to be saved in the project directory, no bad thing in my view as if checked in with the project it sets a standard for the project code format.

I think simply using clang-format for the command would work if the directory is added to the PATH environment variable. Or you'll need to browse to the location of clang-format on your system if it's different you mine.

[Screenshot of dialog window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoeIZ.png)

Comment: Can you explain more how to integrate clang with IAR? Can you please link a tutorial?